# How to analyze time-varying current signal?

Tags: current, ac, signal, current-measurement, appliances

I want to understand the power consumption profile of my electric blanket in order to determine (a) if it's working properly and, if so, (b) how much power it's consuming.

I took some readings with my clamp meter using the below setup. The problem is the readings seem to vary over time. How can I record the signals coming out of my clamp meter?

Oscilloscopes are very expensive so I'm looking for a cheaper alternative. Is there a way to sample a signal coming from out of the clamp meter and, say, store it on my computer for later analysis in a spreadsheet, for example?

Fig. 1. Clamp meter measuring current through one of the wires split by an AC line splitter

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fli38U.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Do the indications vary rapidly and/or strongly? If not, you could manually record the values in a spreadsheet every 10 seconds or so — or even ignore the changes altogether, if they are small. If none of these apply, then unless your meter has a built-in computer interface, your best bet is probably to point a webcam at the screen and record a few minutes of video for future analysis. Of course, the question remains whether the figures you see correspond to reality in any meaningful way, and that's difficult to answer unless you know why they change in the first place, and for that you will need a 'scope.

Comment: How could I use a scope to determine why the current is changing?

Comment: As a scope is much faster than a current meter, it gives more useful information. E.g., if current slowly changes in a particular direction, it could be due to temperature-related resistance changes; if it turns on and off chaotically, you may have a loose contact; if it seems to always turn on at a particular part of the AC cycle, you likely have a triac-based regulator inside, and that may be responsible. It's difficult to foresee all the possibilities, of course. Also, it's important to know how to look at mains voltage with a scope without frying it.